# How to name graph in grafana with elastic datasource

Tags: elasticsearch, grafana

I have stack grafana + elasticsearch. 
How to set labels of charts? 
Now they are all "Max", basing on metric type.
[current query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NxxJo.jpg)

I want to set unique label for every query chart.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `alias` field which is also seen in your screenshot. You may want to check below link to get more information about how to name time series in grafana when elastic search is data source.

https://grafana.com/docs/features/datasources/elasticsearch/#series-naming-alias-patterns